# QGIS 1.8 map composition problem

Tags: qgis, cartography

I have recently installed QGIS 1.8

when I make a map with the adequate layer I switch to the map composition menu and try to insert a map in the white page.

I draw the rectangle but nothing appears although I tried the 3 different option

I also ticked on the show on map for all the layers (show in overview)

can you tell me if this is an installation problem (I have windows XP professional and downloaded the french version) or a trivial problem I am not being able to resolve?

Comment: Did you set the coordinate system for the project (and for each layer)

Answer (score 1):

So,actually there is a guide for map making in qgis 1.8
(http://docs.qgis.org/1.8/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/print_composer.html)

> Adding a current QGIS map canvas to the Print Composer
>
> Rectangle is the default setting. It only displays an empty box with a message ‘Map will be printed here’.
>
> Cache renders the map in the current screen resolution. If case you zoom in or out the composer window, the map is not rendered again but the image will be scaled.
>
> Render means, that if you zoom in or out the composer window, the map will be rendered again, but for space reasons, only up to a maximum resolution.

---

from your question, there might be several situation after you [image] add your "rectangle" to show layer on map composer and now you can see setting from your map item properties
[image]

Situation :

1. you choose rectangle as your update preview
   --> then you have to change it render or cache
2. you already choose cache as your update preview but your Qgis screen (not the map composer) does not show or "zoomed at" wanted layer
   --> then you have to make it (the layer) shown in your qgis desktop screen,
   select cache then update preview